# Exception userinput date time

Tags: python, date, datetime

How do I raise an exception for this user input format?

```
data_base = datetime.datetime.strptime(input("Informe a data base (dd/mm/aaaa): "), "%d/%m/%Y")
data_base = datetime.date(day=int(data_base.strftime("%d")), month=int(data_base.strftime("%m")), year=int(data_base.strftime("%Y")))
print("Data base: " + data_base.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

I tried this, but I keep getting the except message:

```
data_base = datetime.datetime.strptime(input("Informe a data base (dd/mm/aaaa): "), "%d/%m/%Y")
try:
    data_base = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data_base), "%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError:
    print("Incorrect format")
data_base = datetime.date(day=int(data_base.strftime("%d")), month=int(data_base.strftime("%m")), year=int(data_base.strftime("%Y")))
print("Data base: " + data_base.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do here? are you trying to `raise` an exception or catch one?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know the difference between raise and catch. I just need to show "Incorrect format" if the date isn't inserted correctly by user (dd/mm/yyyy). It's probably because the first data_base variable returns %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S. I tried changing the try variable to ```data_base = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data_base), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")```, but no luck.

Comment: Can you do this ` except Exception as e:` instead of `except ValueError:` and `print(e) `also to see why you are getting the error.

Comment: Exception as e returns: `time data '2014-11-12 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
import datetime

data_base = input("Informe a data base (dd/mm/aaaa): ")
try:
    data_base = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data_base), "%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError:
    print("Incorrect format")
else:
    data_base = datetime.date(day=int(data_base.strftime("%d")), month=int(data_base.strftime("%m")), year=int(data_base.strftime("%Y")))
    print("Data base: " + data_base.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

I think the thing holding you up is that you left the `datetime.datetime.strptime` call on your `input` call, which was not inside of your `try` block.